# Como configurar o português no kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, python-kivy

Meu App tem dois arquivos, o *.py e o *.kv, mas estou tendo problemas com acentos na minha GUI. Já tentei resolver no arquivo .py com

> `#encoding: -*- utf-8 -*-`

Mas o problema continua, me ajudem por favor. Configurações: Python 3.6, Kivy 1.10.1.

Comment: Por favor, ao fazer perguntas, ponha um trecho de código o suficiente para reproduzir o problema de forma independente. Isso evita com que quem for responder tenha que recriar todo o seu problema, e cria uma resposta com mais contexto.

Comment: Eu testei o código de "hello world" do Kivy em https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html, com texto em português "alô mundo", e funcionou sem problemas. Sem seu código, não há como responder essa pergunta.

A propósito - nem `#encoding: -*- utf-8 -*-` é uma mágica para resolver tudo que tem acentos, nem tem qualquer efeito em Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz alguns testes aqui, inclusive com o uso de um arquivo .kv, e funciona tudo perfeitamente. mas eu estou num sistema Unix-like e você provavelmente está no Windows.

Suponho que você tenha se certificado de que seus arquivos - tanto o código fonte .py ou os arquivos .kv  estão realmente usando `utf-8` como codificação. Senão, configure o seu editor de programação para usar utf-8.

Em não sendo isso, o que ocorre Kivy está tentando abrir o arquivo na codificação nativa do sistema, indicada pelo Python - e no caso do Windows, ela não é "utf-8".
Um "workaround" rápido seria gravar o seu arquivo .kv na codificação nativa (latin1), mas isso implicaria que sistemas operacionais usando conjuntos de caracteres modernos por padrão, como MacOS, Linux, Android e mesmo uma versão futura do Windows teriam problema com seu app.

Bom - fiz umas buscas, e dá pra ver que provavelmente é esse o caso mesmo:
https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5154

A solução então é, em vez de deixar o Kivy carregar seu arquivo .kv automaticamente, usar o "Builder.load_string" e ler o arquivo manualmente, passando a codificação de forma explícita.

Para isso, em vez de ter o nome do arquivo .kv igual ao nome da sua classe "App", como é necessário para o kivy carregar o arquivo automaticamente, 
ponha qualquer outro nome no arquivo .kv, e no método `.build` do seu app, faça:

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(open("meu_arquivo.kv", encoding="utf-8").read(), rulesonly=True)
        return MyMainWidget()
```

Note que usando o "load_string", o código que lê o arquivo .kv passa a estar sob seu controle, então é só usr o `open` do Python, forçando a codificação de texto para utf-8.